# cannot realloc a double pointer dynamic memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc, realloc

I tried to increase a double pointer buffer in another method/function. However, the size of the allocated buffer does not changes. Here is the code I tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change_buffer_size(char ** buffer)
{
     *buffer = realloc(*buffer, sizeof(char) * 2);
}

int main()
{
    char **buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1); 
    *buffer[0] = 'H';
    change_buffer_size(buffer);
    *buffer[1] = 'i';
    printf("%s\n", *buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

Comment: *Always* `realloc` with a *temporary* pointer. When `realloc` fails it returns `NULL` which will overwrite your original pointer causing a memory leak. E.g. `void *tmp = realloc (*buffer * 2 * sizeof **buffer); if (!tmp) { perror ("realloc-tmp"); return; }; *buffer = tmp; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char **buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
```

This is wrong. You now have a `char**`, so the thing that it points to is a `char*`, but there's only enough room in it for a `char`. You also only allocated one layer of the double pointer.

```
*buffer[0] = 'H';
```

This line causes the segfault because of the above problems. It's trying to write to memory in an undefined location.

The best way to fix this is to just allocate the first layer normally, use `&` where necessary, and only use `malloc` for the second layer.

Also, `%s` doesn't stop writing until it sees a null byte, so you need to allocate and write one of them. Here's how you fix it all:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change_buffer_size(char ** buffer)
{
     *buffer = realloc(*buffer, sizeof(char) * 3);
}

int main()
{
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1); 
    buffer[0] = 'H';
    change_buffer_size(&buffer);
    buffer[1] = 'i';
    buffer[2] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. could you please tell me how can modify the buffer inside the ```change_buffer_size``` function ? for example, ```buffer[1] = 'i';``` after realloc. I get the segmentation fault again.

Comment: @vortex Note that `buffer` is a different type in `change_buffer_size` and in `main` now. What you wrote is correct in `main`, but in `change_buffer_size`, you'd need to do `(*buffer)[1] = 'i';` instead.

Comment: thanks again. Could you please elaborate a bit why should I use such a syntax?

Comment: @vortex Because `buffer` is a `char**` there, so you need to do `(*buffer)` first to get a `char*`, and then `[1]` to get a `char` that you can finally write `'i'` to.

Comment: You still invoke *Undefined Behavior* -- a lack of a *nul-terminating* character when treating `buffer` as a string in `printf("%s\n", buffer);` `buffer` is too short by one.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a good answer by [@JosephSible](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7509065/joseph-sible-reinstate-monica) but there is one further point that needs making about the use of `realloc`. I've alluded to this in the comment under the original question. When using `realloc`, you must always `realloc` using a *temporary* pointer to capture the return of `realloc`.

Why? When (not if) `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL`. If you assign the return directly to the pointer you are attempting to reallocate for, you overwrite the pointer to your existing block of memory with `NULL` losing your reference to the original block creating a memory leak. For example, you do not want to:

```
    *buffer = realloc (*buffer, 2);       /* sizeof(char) is always 1 */
```

Instead, use a temporary pointer and validate the reallocation succeeds before assigning the reallocated block to your original pointer, e.g.

```
    void * tmp = realloc (*buffer, 2);
    if (!tmp) {     /* validate EVERY allocation & reallocation */
        perror ("realloc-*buffer");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);        /* or handle as desired, e.g return NULL, etc.. */
    }
    *buffer = tmp;  /* now assign the reallocated block to your pointer */
```

A couple of comments on your original post. Recall in C a string must end with a *nul-terminating* character. You cannot simply assign `buffer[0] = 'H';` and treat `buffer` as a string. The *nul-termianting* character (`'\0'`, or simply `0`) must follow, so you would need `buffer[1] = 0;` before calling `printf("%s\n", *buffer);`

Avoid using *Magic-Numbers* in your code. Your `change_buffer_size()` function hardcodes the reallocation to size using the magic-number `2`. (not very useful). Instead, at least pass the desired size as a parameter so your function is reusable, e.g.

```
char *change_buffer_size (char **buffer, size_t nchar)
{
    void *tmp = realloc (*buffer, nchar * sizeof **buffer);
    if (!tmp) { /* validate EVERY allocation/reallocation */
        perror ("change_buffer_size()-realloc");
        return NULL;
    }

    return *buffer = tmp;   /* assign new block to *buffer, return */
}
```

(**note:** changing the return type to `char*` allows you to indicate success/failure of the function through the return as well as having direct access to the reallocated block of memory on success)

Now is you want to reallocate your buffer to 2-characters, just pass `2` as `nchar`, etc.. That combined with a short example that reallocates and adds a character to your buffer at a time (while ensuring it is always *nul-terminated*) could be something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *change_buffer_size (char **buffer, size_t nchar)
{
    void *tmp = realloc (*buffer, nchar * sizeof **buffer);
    if (!tmp) { /* validate EVERY allocation/reallocation */
        perror ("change_buffer_size()-realloc");
        return NULL;
    }

    return *buffer = tmp;   /* assign new block to *buffer, return */
}

int main (void) {

    size_t nchar = 1;   /* character counter */
    char *str = "hello world!", *buffer = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (!change_buffer_size(&buffer, nchar + 1))    /* alloc nchar + 1 */
            return 1;
        buffer[nchar-1] = str[i];           /* copy char from str to buffer */
        buffer[nchar++] = 0;                /* nul-terminate buffer */
        printf ("buffer: '%s'\n", buffer);  /* print current buffer contents */
    }

    free (buffer);      /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

(**note:** don't forget to `free()` the memory you allocate. Yes, here it will be freed on program exit, but build good habits early -- you will not always be working in `main()`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/realloccharbuf
buffer: 'h'
buffer: 'he'
buffer: 'hel'
buffer: 'hell'
buffer: 'hello'
buffer: 'hello '
buffer: 'hello w'
buffer: 'hello wo'
buffer: 'hello wor'
buffer: 'hello worl'
buffer: 'hello world'
buffer: 'hello world!'
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/realloccharbuf
==19740== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19740== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19740== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19740== Command: ./bin/realloccharbuf
==19740==
buffer: 'h'
buffer: 'he'
buffer: 'hel'
buffer: 'hell'
buffer: 'hello'
buffer: 'hello '
buffer: 'hello w'
buffer: 'hello wo'
buffer: 'hello wor'
buffer: 'hello worl'
buffer: 'hello world'
buffer: 'hello world!'
==19740==
==19740== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19740==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19740==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 1,114 bytes allocated
==19740==
==19740== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19740==
==19740== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19740== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I just realized something: you say "When using realloc, you must always realloc using a temporary pointer to capture the return of realloc", but why, if you're just going to `exit`? To quote Raymond Chen, "[The building is being demolished. Don’t bother sweeping the floor and emptying the trash cans and erasing the whiteboards. And don’t line up at the exit to the building so everybody can move their in/out magnet to out. All you’re doing is making the demolition team wait for you to finish these pointless housecleaning tasks.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683)"

Comment: If you are just going to exit -- it doesn't matter. But when teaching, you always present the general case first and then move on to the exceptions. That way if the OP moves the code to a function  -- they are covered. You know C and know enough to forward think from wherever you are in your code and determine whether an action is necessary. That comes from experience more so that being something you can teach as an exception in a answer (It's doable, it just muddies the water a bit)